# How to get array of strings from output php

Tags: php, arrays

I do a `print_r($my_var)`

and get a result like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => maa@hotmail.com ) [1] => Array ( [email] => mee@gmail.com ) )
```

How to get a new array like

```
$mails=    array( 'maa@hotmail.com','mee@gmail.com' );
```

Comment: use a loop. basic php.

Comment: I was trying `foreach ($myvar->result() as $val) $to .= $val->email . ", ";` but to get rid ot that last comma?

Comment: Use `rtrim($to, ', ')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$mails = array_map(function ($x){
    return $x['email'];
}, $my_var);
```

[**Codepad Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/d27iSs)

**Update**

Using a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop instead of [array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$mails = array();
foreach($my_var as $emailArr){
    $mails[] = $emailArr['email'];
}
```

[**Codepad Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9e03Ho)

Comment: Is it other way withouth using a mapping function?

Comment: @JohnBallinger `array_values($my_var[0])` just returns an array containing the first email address, not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

array_values($myvar[0]);

// Will return the values inside you array ( I noticed your array was nested, so I did the values of he 0 element).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Highly recommend just having a little read of all the available array functions just quickly so you can see what is possible.